# Binding for events in wxpython only works for last one

Tags: python, wxpython, signals-slots

I am trying to populate the screen with multiple buttons automatically *(using for loop)*

Here is the snippet:

```
    i = 0
    for w in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]:
        by.append(wx.Button(panel,label=w,pos = wx.Point(50*i,0)))
        by[i].Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,lambda event: self.OnClicked(event,by[i]))
        i += 1
    i = 0
```

when the event occurs, since I set the `i = 0`, all of the events are routed to the first button, even if I click on the last button. I know that if I set the slot with out the for loop it would work. But lets say I need to create about 50 buttons on a screen, and I want to do it automatically. How would I set the slot?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the lambda expression `lambda event: self.OnClicked(event,by[i]))`. You can read more on the basic problem here: [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python).

But in short: The `i` is not fixed at the creation of the lambda expression. After the loop has ended, all the lambda expressions still refer to `i`. That means all of them have the same value.

A dirty fix would be to use this instead:

```
by[i].Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,lambda event, i=i: self.OnClicked(event,by[i]))
```

But it might be better to use another helper function to do the variable binding:

```
def addOnClicked(i,w):
    by.append(wx.Button(panel,label=w,pos = wx.Point(50*i,0)))
    by[i].Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,lambda event: self.OnClicked(event,by[i]))

for i in range(8):
    addOnClicked(i,i+1)
```